# YouTube APIs - YouTube Studio managed brand account missing in OAuth flow

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When going through the YouTube API OAuth flow, brand accounts that are managed through YouTube Studio are missing.

Going through the OAuth flow you have to select your Google account, and then you're prompted to select your account or brand account. Here I notice that Brand accounts you received access to through the Brand account's permissions management are shown, but the ones you received access for through the YouTube Studio permissions management do not.

I cannot seem to find anything about this, so I was wondering if anyone knows whether this is intended behavior or not?

Comment: I think you will have better luck posting this on the  [Issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)  or wait and see if [stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) responds to your question they might know.

Comment: (@DaImTo: I go by the pronouns *he/him* -- if your *they* is not a typo.)

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks so much! In the API docs they link to Stackoverflow so I didn't know the issue forum existed.

Comment: @Nyveria: Quote from the official YouTube Data API's [How to Get Help](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) page: **[*Issue Tracker*](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). 
Something wrong? Send us a bug report!**

Comment: @stvar Hmm that's odd, when I go to that page I'm not seeing that text. I'm seeing: "We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags."

Anyway, I'll post my question there then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @stvar i will try to use that in the future but on SO i tend to always go with gender neutral.  As I cant count how many times i have been gotten sir on SO.

Comment: @Nyveria: Only have to scroll down that page a bit! SO is not Google support, in spite of the claims that page makes.

Comment: @stvar Ah, thanks! That's good to know.